# encountered : identifier expected cross, having,inner left, limit,order,right,where,commacausedby:exception syntax error

Tags: sql, hive, impala

my query looks like

but I am getting error

```
select a.account_number,b.reference_acc
from hdd.master_record format1 a
join hdd.monetary b
on a.load_date = b.load_date
```

can anyone tell me what is the issue with this query?

Comment: What is error you getting, please share here.

Comment: Error while executing a query in Impala[HY000]: from hdd.master_record format1 a ^encountered: IDENTIFIER expected: CROSS,INNER,HAVING,LIMIT,LEFT,USING,WHERE,COMMA CAUSED BY EXCEPTION: Syntax error

Comment: please remove `format1' aliases it's two only keep a.